# Renci SSH.Net - how to properly use RemoveForwardedPort() on Linux and .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, ssh, ssh.net

I have a problem with Renci SSH.NET implementation on Raspbian 10.
My scenario is long running SSH tunneling connection with a number of ForwardedPortRemote's.
In required places I do:

For SshClient:

```
sshClient.ErrorOccurred += delegate (object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e){ . . . }
```

and for each forwarded port:

```
portRemote.Exception += delegate (Object source, ExceptionEventArgs args){ . . . }
```

and then handle these events.\

Since it is long running connection, when it gets disrupted (cable plugged off, internet down etc), the software then tries to reconnect the ssh client. As soon as the Internet access is available again, it reconnects.
When the connection gets interrupted and the above events fire, I want to stop/dispose/remove forwarded ports from the ssh client, so later when the new connection is established, there are no leftover unused/stopped ports registered on the SshClient.
The problem is when I call SshClient.RemoveForwardedPort(port) after above events are raised, it throws "Client not connected" exception and doesn't remove the ports. It throws it both when it gets disconnected and after reconnection too. Thus I cannot dispose and remove of "old" forwarded unused ports.
Question: How or at what point can I remove those ports properly? Or eventually can I reuse them?

Appreciate any help/ideas.

Comment: The forwarding should be taken down with the SSH connection, isn't it?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The port forwarding is of course stopped as soon as the connection goes down. The port forwarding registered with SSH client (with SshClient.AddForwardedPort(port)) however, stays and must be removed with SshClient.RemoveForwardedPort(port). This method however, when called after the SSH connection error exception, throws another exception (client not connected) and fails to remove the port forwarding. I don't want to dispose of the SSH client and want to re-use it after the connection is back up.